# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error in this code

```
$(function() {
  $(".letter-container h1 a").lettering();
});
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Where is your HTML? plus give some more information about what you want to do and post your complete jQuery code.

Comment: 1. Determine what it is that is undefined (probably `lettering`). 2. Figure out why you think it should be defined. 3. Use that to identify why it isn't.

Comment: What is .lettering()?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is exactly what the error message says: your selector `$(".letter-container h1 a")` returns an object that does *not* have a method `lettering()`. So the questions you have to answer are:

- what kind of object do you actually get from the selector
- where should that function actually be defined

Comment: personally I find this a bit misleading mentioning the selector which never has anything to do with whether a method is defined or not. `$('failedSelector')` will always be an object ( assuming jQuery is available)